# Installing MS Visual studio 2010 when MS Visual Studio 2012 is already there

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, installation

I have MS visual studio 2012 installed on my computer.Now I am in need of MS Visual studio 2010. Will this installation create an issue ? The reason is that I have a project done in 2010 version and I've been struggling to build it in 2012.

Is anyone there who experienced problems after installing 2010 when they already had 2012 or a higher version ?

I found some forums on the internet, and most of them say it's not recommended. I'm confused.

Or else, is there a way to remove MS visual studio 2012 from the computer ? I mean, to remove it completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install different versions of Visual Studio side-by-side with no issues.

In fact, it's usually better to install the later version first, then older versions.